# cobertura parsing error(cobertura.javancss.parser.ParseException)

Tags: java, testing, code-coverage, maven-cobertura-plugin

I am fairly new to deployment and code coverage issues and now i have a problem ,my application uses cobertura maven plugin 2.7 and covertura version 2.1.1 and java 8. I am getting an error while running my deployment in the cobertura report

```
[ERROR] net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.ParseException: Encountered " ">" "> "" at line 45, column 36.
Was expecting one of:
"assert" ...
"boolean" ...
"byte" ...
"char" ...
"double" ...
"enum" ...
"false" ...
"float" ...
"int" ...
"long" ...
"new" ...
"null" ...
"short" ...
"super" ...
"this" ...
"true" ...
"void" ...
<INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
<FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...
<CHARACTER_LITERAL> ...
<STRING_LITERAL> ...
<IDENTIFIER> ...
"(" ...
"!" ...
"~" ...
"++" ...
"--" ...
"+" ...
"-" ...

at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.generateParseException(JavaParser.java:10490)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.jj_consume_token(JavaParser.java:10366)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.UnaryExpression(JavaParser.java:3175)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.MultiplicativeExpression(JavaParser.java:3090)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.AdditiveExpression(JavaParser.java:3085)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.ShiftExpression(JavaParser.java:3027)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.RelationalExpression(JavaParser.java:2990)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.InstanceOfExpression(JavaParser.java:2977)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.AssigmentExpression(JavaParser.java:2959)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.EqualityExpression(JavaParser.java:2886)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.AndExpression(JavaParser.java:2860)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.ExclusiveOrExpression(JavaParser.java:2843)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.InclusiveOrExpression(JavaParser.java:2826)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.ConditionalAndExpression(JavaParser.java:2808)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.ConditionalOrExpression(JavaParser.java:2790)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.ConditionalExpression(JavaParser.java:2774)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.Expression(JavaParser.java:2718)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.ArgumentList(JavaParser.java:3620)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.Arguments(JavaParser.java:3610)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.PrimarySuffix(JavaParser.java:3511)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.PrimaryExpression(JavaParser.java:3384)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.PostfixExpression(JavaParser.java:3330)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus(JavaParser.java:3237)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.UnaryExpression(JavaParser.java:3171)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.MultiplicativeExpression(JavaParser.java:3090)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.AdditiveExpression(JavaParser.java:3061)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.ShiftExpression(JavaParser.java:3027)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.RelationalExpression(JavaParser.java:2990)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.InstanceOfExpression(JavaParser.java:2977)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.AssigmentExpression(JavaParser.java:2959)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.EqualityExpression(JavaParser.java:2886)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.AndExpression(JavaParser.java:2860)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.ExclusiveOrExpression(JavaParser.java:2843)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.InclusiveOrExpression(JavaParser.java:2826)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.ConditionalAndExpression(JavaParser.java:2808)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.ConditionalOrExpression(JavaParser.java:2790)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.ConditionalExpression(JavaParser.java:2774)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.Expression(JavaParser.java:2718)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.VariableInitializer(JavaParser.java:1744)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.VariableDeclarator(JavaParser.java:1672)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.LocalVariableDeclaration(JavaParser.java:4019)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.BlockStatement(JavaParser.java:3941)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.Block(JavaParser.java:3934)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.MethodDeclaration(JavaParser.java:1987)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.ClassBodyDeclaration(JavaParser.java:1039)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.ClassBody(JavaParser.java:898)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.UnmodifiedClassDeclaration(JavaParser.java:824)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.ClassDeclaration(JavaParser.java:728)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.TypeDeclaration(JavaParser.java:575)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.CompilationUnit(JavaParser.java:318)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.parse(JavaParser.java:100)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.Javancss._measureSource(Javancss.java:192)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.Javancss._measureRoot(Javancss.java:268)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.Javancss.<init>(Javancss.java:347)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.JavancssFactory.newInstance(JavancssFactory.java:40)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ComplexityCalculator.getFunctionMetricsForSingleFile(ComplexityCalculator.java:243)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ComplexityCalculator.getAccumlatedCCNForSingleFile(ComplexityCalculator.java:143)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ComplexityCalculator.getCCNForSourceFileNameInternal(ComplexityCalculator.java:273)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ComplexityCalculator.getCCNForPackageInternal(ComplexityCalculator.java:208)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ComplexityCalculator.getCCNForProject(ComplexityCalculator.java:174)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.xml.XMLReport.<init>(XMLReport.java:70)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.xml.XMLReportFormatStrategy.save(XMLReportFormatStrategy.java:18)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.NativeReport.export(NativeReport.java:31)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.CompositeReport.export(CompositeReport.java:19)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ReportMain.parseArgumentsAndReport(ReportMain.java:91)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ReportMain.generateReport(ReportMain.java:141)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ReportMain.main(ReportMain.java:151)
net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.ParseException: Encountered " ">" "> "" at line 48, column 36.
`Was expecting one of:
"assert" ...
"boolean" ...
"byte" ...
"char" ...
"double" ...
"enum" ...
"false" ...
"float" ...
"int" ...
"long" ...
"new" ...
"null" ...
"short" ...
"super" ...
"this" ...
"true" ...
"void" ...
<INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
<FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...
<CHARACTER_LITERAL> ...
<STRING_LITERAL> ...
<IDENTIFIER> ...
"(" ...
"!" ...
"~" ...
"++" ...
"--" ...
"+" ...
"-" ...
```

It would be great to receive some kind of suggestions as this is a blocker for the application,Thank You

Answer (score 1):

javancss can't handle certain Java8 Code and you get an error while parsing.

The last commit was 2 years ago so you have to try an alternative like [SonarCube](http://www.sonarqube.org/)

Answer (score 0):

While the javancss plugin is updated https://blog.sonarsource.com/the_next_major_version_of_javancss_is_on_its_way

I recommend:

Option 1: For the javancss plugin, the specific class could be excluded:

```
<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>javancss-maven-plugin</artifactId>

        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/bar.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/foobar.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>

      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Option 2: the errors could be ignored:

```
<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>javancss-maven-plugin</artifactId>

        <configuration>
          <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>

        </configuration>

      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

https://www.mojohaus.org/javancss-maven-plugin/